# Copy file to /system/bin/ in android11/12

Tags: android, system, android-11

I am trying copy file from raw to /system/bin/ location in android11/12.

Please find below code :

Manifest permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

MainActivity:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    YourFile(R.raw.test);
}

private void YourFile(int Resource) {

    String pathSystemBin = "/system/bin"+ "/test_new"; // File path


    try{
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(Resource);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        out = new FileOutputStream(pathSystemBin);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            end();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void end () {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Getting below error :

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/bin/test
_new : open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: `(Read-only file system)` Not even that!

Comment: `Manifest permission :` You do not need any of those permissions for what you are up to.

Answer (score 0):

Try new File("/system/bin").exists().

Try new File("/system/bin").canRead().

Try new File("/system/bin").canWrite().

before you try other things.

Comment: new File("/system/bin").exists() : true , new File("/system/bin").canRead(): false  & new File("/system/bin").canWrite()  false . Getting boolean value like above